# Knowing the message, can a signature be derived from an address or pubkey?

Tags: signature, ecdsa

**tl;dr** if I were to sign an Ethereum message, eg. **`web3.eth.personal.sign("Bitcoin", "SOME-ETH-ADDRESS")`,** would it be reasonably safe to use a 32-byte hash of the signature as the private key for a Bitcoin wallet?

---

Is it possible to calculate the signature hash of a signed message, using eg.

**`web3.eth.personal.sign("Hello world", "0x11f4d0A3c12e86B4b5F39B213F7E19D048276DAe", "test password!")`** [taken from the web3 docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.2/web3-eth-personal.html#sign)

which would return **`0x30755ed65396facf86c53e6217c52b4daebe72aa4941d89635409de4c9c7f9466d4e9aaec7977f05e923889b33c0d0dd27d7226b6e6f56ce737465c5cfd04be400`,**

if you **DO NOT** have the private key?

Specifically, if the message being signed is **KNOWN**, and the address and/or pubkey of the signer are **KNOWN**, can the signature hash be calculated by a 3rd-party.

---

The use-case is to use the signature *(32-byte hashed)* as the **PRIVATE KEY** for generating other addresses (non-Ethereum).

I saw this question, 
[Can a message hash be recovered from a signature?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/30538/can-a-message-hash-be-recovered-from-a-signature), however, this line is a bit confusing:

> It should be noted that while computing the message hash is infeasible, it is possible to check guesses, if the message was not salted before hashing (which it usually isn't).

Thanks!

Comment: In general hashes can't be reverse-engineered. But if you know some of the inputs you can try guessing the rest of the inputs and produce the hashes for those and see if the end result is correct - this is a bruteforce way of finding the missing input.

Comment: @LauriPeltonen so brute force is __always__ an option. my concern is, let's say I use eg. `Bitcoin_Wallet_1` as the message I sign. Would the 65-byte hash that's produced be any less secure than the 32-byte key that I'm using to sign the message? I'm guessing the answer is __YES__, but I'd like to know "reasonably" by how much. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formulating an answer of some sorts based on the comments.

So in general hashes can't be reversed. Once you calculate `hash(A) = B` there is no way to calculate `A` if you know `B`.

However if `A` is something short enough (for example a phonenumber) or something guessable (for example your first name) one can simply try all combinations of `A` and apply the hash function to that and see if it matches `B`. That can be done fully offline so it can be done in an efficient manner. This is a brute force way of finding `A`.

If I understood correctly you want to do further calculations by using `B` as private key  for a public address so something like `public_address = getAddr(B)` where `getAddr` includes hashing and elliptic curve stuff.

So if someone wanted to hack your private key they would basically still need to guess `A`. Or just guess the private key - whichever is easier. So security wise I don't see a big difference here. Do note that there may be other attack vectors based on how you store the different values and so on.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've been working on this __wallet model__ for a few weeks now, and so far I don't really see any "significant" weaknesses in security. Will update if anything develops in the future.